# How can check running dev_appserver.py with datastore-emulator

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, dev-appserver-2, datastore-mode-emulator

I installed all env for google cloud app engine development server and datastore emulator.
And I run the datastore emulator first.

> gcloud beta emulators datastore start

and start dev-appengine server.

> dev_appserver.py app.yaml

---

How can I check devappserver works with the datastore emulator?

datastore env is DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST_PATH=localhost:8081/datastore
localhost:8000/datastore works normally, but localhost:8081/datastore doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue solved.

Emulator Project Name on the part of using datastore client towards emulator:8081 and the dev_appserver application name were different.

I wrote "application: my-project-id" in app.yaml file for dev_appserver application name.

"set DATASTORE_PROJECT_ID=my-project-id" for dev_appserver application name ([GCP Datastore Emulator](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator))

Run dev_appserver

> dev_appserver.py app.yaml --support_datastore_emulator=true --datastore_emulator_port=8081

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting `--datastore_emulator_port` when running `dev_appserver.py` to the port where your datastore emulator is running?

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/migrate-cloud-datastore-emulator#using_dev_appserver_with_the_datastore_emulator

EDIT:
Also, it looks like `dev_appserver.py` is supposed to print the following line if it is using the Cloud Datastore Emulator

> ... Using Cloud Datastore Emulator.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to do with a command line like: 
dev_appserver.py app.yaml --support_datastore_emulator=true --dev_appserver_log_level=debug --datastore_emulator_port=8081

Then they say: "Using Cloud Datastore Emulator.", "Dev App Server is now running.", "export DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8081", "Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080", "Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000"

And I can access emulator datastore using port 8081. 
Btw when I inserted some data into emulator datastore, I can't find data in localhost:8000/datastore.